# Multi-Factor Kruskal Wallis Test in R

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, nonparametric, kruskal-wallis-test, heterogeneity

I have a dataset where the response variable is a non-normally distributed proportion and is heterogenous with respect to all factors. I cannot seem to transform the response variable into anything resembling a normal distribution. I want to see which of my 4 factors has a significant effect on the response variable, so I want to use something like a multi-factor Kruskal-Wallis test in R. I found the Scheirer–Ray–Hare extension of the KW test in R, but it can only handle 2 factors. Is there a function in R for 3 or more factors, or are there alternative models that I can use that are robust to the violations of the assumptions above?

Comment: My first thought was to try a quantile regression.